# Visual Studio 2008 crashes

Tags: visual-studio

When I open a aspx page, it crashes. Doesn't happen when I'm on SAFE MODE. It seems to be connected to Visual SVN. I'm also using Telerik, but telerik seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, this is a unique problem to your environment and difficult to troubleshoot with light details. I'd obviously recommend trying to uninstall the Visual SVN plug-in and see if that impacts VS stability. If VS stability improves, problem solved; if not, keep removing/uninstalling VS plug-ins to trace the issue.

If you ultimately still have issues with all plug-ins removed, a repair install of VS 2008 may help.

Sorry this help isn't more targeted. Try some trouble hunting and let us know if we can help further.

Comment: tried repairing the VS, still didn't work. I also removed the VisualSVN. I'm doubting that uninstall-reinstall would do any good, but i will still try. any other ideas guys?

Comment: So, a clean, repaired VS 2008 with no plug-ins installed still crashes? If that is the case, try two steps: 1) Run VS 2008 in safemode ("devenv /safemode" from command prompt). If all works, restart VS 2008, and 2) Start disabling all plug-ins via Tools > Add-In Manager until problem goes away. If VS works in safemode, that should indicate that there is /some/ plug-in causing the problem.